# How can i trigger help key F1 action by click on Jbutton

Tags: jbutton

Right now i'm working on JavaHelp content.

Basically, First solution, after you select the the selected function from the tree menu or node (JTree), and pressed help key (F1) it will popup the specific JavaHelp content based on selected node.

Right now, im trying to add Help button, user first need to select function from the tree menu   or node and click on Help button i created. it suppose work exactly as the first solution but right now, it doesn't popup the correct content.

How can i make the Help button to trigger the F1 key action? meaning when we select the node, it already have a focus n can directly popup if we pressed F1 key, the help button would probably just trigger the F1 key action.

I heard about doClick function or keys binding, any ideas on this?

Thanks

Regards,
Aznimah

Hi, i try to implement the keybinding to trigger the F1 key action when user click on Help button. But i clueless how to set code to trigger the F1 key action. Here is some code :

action button:

```
final String helpIconLocation = new String("/icons/help_new.png");
        iconResource = CustomizedToolbar.class.getResource(helpIconLocation);
        icon = new ImageIcon(iconResource);
        actionButton = new JButton(icon);
        actionButton.setFocusable(false);
        actionButton.addActionListener(new JavaHelpHandler());
```

ActionListener:

```
private class JavaHelpHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            Action javaHelpF1KeyAction = new AbstractAction();
            KeyStroke helpKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F1, 0);
            MainApp.getMainAppPanel().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                    helpKeyStroke, "F1");
            MainApp.getMainAppPanel().getActionMap().put("F1", javaHelpF1KeyAction);

        }

    }


    private class AbstractAction implements ActionListener, Action {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TO display popup javaHelp content
            HelpSystemUtil.getInstance().enableHelpFromFocus(actionButton);
        }

        @Override
        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public Object getValue(String key) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void putValue(String key, Object value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

How can i set actionMap to trigger the F1 keys action? really need help on this

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way you could do is to create a Key Listener.

[KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

There are several ways to do this. Here's one:

```
    yourComponent.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter () { 
         @Override
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

              if ( e == YOUR_KEY_CODE ) {
                   // Do something
              }

         }
    });
```

Anyway, key code for F1 is 112

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.

I just go through the link given, but not fully understand.

Right now, i just select the tree menu or node and directly clicked the help button. how can i relate the help button to trigger the help key F1 action?

Comment: Yes thank you so much for the reply,

Anyway, i have another questions, how can i trigger the F1 keys function, meaning make it FI keys programaticaly without need to keypressed on keyboard

Comment: You could use KeyBindings instead. Docs can be found here [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Hi, already update some code related to keybinding, but clueless to set code to trigger F1 key action through button click, any ideas on this?